# How to navigate to bash_profile

Tags: command-line-interface

I am following a tutorial and cant figure out how to get to the bash_profile 
The tutorial says

"Add the following line to the .bash_profile file in your home folder"

//then there is code

but I dont know how to get there. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The file `.bash_profile` should be in your home directory. You might be having trouble finding it because it is a hidden file. A file with a period (like `.bash_profile`) is hidden. You can list hidden files like this: `ls -a`. Do you see it now? You will need to be in your home directory to see this file in particular.

You can **c**hange **d**irectories with the `cd` command (`~` is short for home):

```
cd ~
```

After navigating to your home directory, you can open `.bash_profile` with your editor of choice, or just add the lines to the end of the file from the command line:

```
echo "What you want to add" >> .bash_profile
```

If you do not want to travel to your home directory, you can adapt the code above to add lines to `.bash_profile` from any directory:

```
echo "What you want to add" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Thanks for all the great info! Can I cd into .bash_profile? When i try it says its not a directory. I know im in the right place because I can see it

Comment: You are correct, you cannot `cd` into files. You can only use `cd` to **c**hange **d**irectories. If you want to edit the file from the command line, you can try `nano`. [Here is a basic guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Nano/Basics_Guide). I would not recommend that you try `vim` or `emacs` yet. If `nano` is still a little bit over your head, then I would try a graphical text editor instead.